# Regex expression String contains alpha bates and arithmetic operator -

Tags: regex

I need Regex expression it Start with alpha bates  and it contains - symbol please help me

Example: One-Two-three

thanks

Comment: This isn't a " I need ... please help" page. Please invest some time in your question to make it understandable and valuable. Have a look at [John Skeets: Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and [Matt Gemmells: What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z-]*$
```

should do it

Comment: The `+` isn't really necessary.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes tim you are right.

Comment: thanks for reply for my condition its not working i get string from server 5441l545-1+917554533ONE-TWO-THREE  in this i need ONE-TWO-THREE  only

Comment: @user3073785: Then why didn't you write that in your question? Were we supposed to guess that?